# React Native trigger Facebook Login from Image on click

Tags: android, node.js, mobile, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm new on React Native and currently I'm working on a facebook login using react-native, but I'm using custom Image instead of button, is there any sdk to support this? There are so many sdk outhere but, they all use Button instead of Image.

I've been searching everywhere but got no luck. I'm using `TouchableHighlight` for triggering the click, but still I don't know how to login with FB when I click on the Image.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood properly, you should wrap image with touchable highlight and triger action on press.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress=this.login()> // yours action should go here
  <Image />
</ TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to integrate your react native project with facebook login react native sdk, just simply follow their official documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started

alternatively, you can use a wrapper like this one, https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login.

They all have a pretty clear documentation to follow along.